# How to draw image using FileDialog in Java

Tags: java, swing

Need to display selected in FileDialog image, but thats somewhy didnt work. When i try to choose image it throws exception javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't create an ImageInputStream!

I think problem is in getDirectory() , but dont know how to fix.

```
public ImageShow() throws IOException {
    super("Pictures");
    setSize(1024,768);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    buttonOpen = new JButton("Open file");

    buttonPanel.add(buttonOpen);


    actions();
    fileDialog();
    add(buttonPanel);

    image = ImageIO.read(new File(fd.getDirectory()));
    imageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
    buttonPanel.add(imageLabel);

}


public void fileDialog() {
    fd = new FileDialog(new JFrame(), "Choose file");
    fd.setVisible(true);
}




public void actions() {
    buttonOpen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            fileDialog();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: Do you mean a Image Preview within a JFileChooser Dialog window? If so then check this out: http://java-demos.blogspot.in/2013/11/add-image-preview-pane-to-jfilechooser.html

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Always copy/paste error and exception output! 3) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 4) Use the Swing based `JFileChooser` rather than the AWT based `FileDialog`.

Comment: So i mean i need to show image on a JFrame.

 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1306)
 at Neuroweb.ImageShow.<init>(ImageShow.java:43)
 at Neuroweb.ImageShow.main(ImageShow.java:23)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Answer (score 1):

```
image = ImageIO.read(new File(fd.getDirectory()));
```

A directory is not an image!  Try instead **[`getFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html#getFile--)** which:

> Gets the **selected file** of this file dialog. If the user selected CANCEL, the returned file is null.

But as I said in comments..

> Use the Swing based `JFileChooser` rather than the AWT based `FileDialog`.

And be sure to consult the avialable documentation when using methods.